# Size of svg file with text converted to paths

Tags: svg, file-size

I'm using an svg image as a full screen page for reference material. That way I can have it stretch to fit whatever width of screen is being used.
Example here: https://aloba.net/dinoJump/hints/index.html (be patient, it will load!)
Seemed like a good idea, but - once I convert the text to paths the files become huge (and slow to load). Any suggestions? Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree? (I save them in Inkscape as optimized). Most is svg - but the program blocks are embedded png reduced with pngquant.

Comment: You need to convert a_textless_dino.svg to PNG format and then optimize it on PNG optimization sites. I can't think of any other solution.

Comment: Good idea, however I've just come across BoxySVG. Boxy make it easy to embed the font descriptions in the SVG. For example, an optimized SVG with text converted to paths came out of Inkscape at over 600 kB. Using BoxySVG with the font embedded under 200 kB. PNGs optimized through pngquant come out even smaller, but with SVGs I have the flexibility to hand edit to make shapes clickable, as well as reliable quality at different image sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experimenting with [BoxySVG](https://boxy-svg.com/). Boxy supports embedding font descriptions in the SVG file, so there's no need to convert text to paths. That makes the file sizes much more manageable. Boxy is proprietary, but there's no charge for using the Linux version.

I have no affiliation to BoxySVG. Embedding fonts is useful, but for some things good old Inkscape is still a better fit.

Comment: Suggestion - It is normal to add a declaration of affiliation or non-affiliation.  This helps the bot to not flag it as spam.